# Select One Month Before date in imacro

Tags: imacros

How can I select 30 days less (before) date from today in `imacro`?

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ACTION:ReportAll.aspx ATTR=ID:ContentPlaceHolderMiddle_TxtFromDate CONTENT={{!NOW:dd/mm/yyyy}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Play this and apply to your macro:

```
SET D "var d = new Date();"
' 30 days before
ADD D "d.setDate(d.getDate() - 30);"
' or 1 month before
'ADD D "d.setMonth(d.getMonth() - 1);"
ADD D "d = ('0' + d.getDate()).slice(-2) + '/' + ('0' + (d.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '/' + d.getFullYear();"
SET dateBefore EVAL("eval('{{D}}'); d;")
PROMPT {{dateBefore}}
```